# Performance issue using Z3 for linear arithmetic queries

Tags: z3

I am writing a static analysis tools that needs to perform some queries to an oracle solving linear integer arithmetic problems. For my first version, I implemented a decision procedure for Presburger arithmetic in OCaml (for fun, and profit). On big programs my decision procedure becomes the bottleneck so I decided to move to Z3.

My first results are disappointing, so I think I am doing something wrong with the Z3 API. I observe that, on simple programs, the analysis is more than 100 times slower with Z3 than with my naive home-brewed implementation. After some trivial benchmarking I think the culprit is:

```
let unsat ps =
  let open Z3.Solver in
  let solver = mk_solver ctx None in
  add solver [ps];
  check solver [] <> SATISFIABLE
```

I use this function hundreds of times (thousands on big programs). The problem, encoded in `ps` is of the form `(not (implies (and X X X X X) Y))` where the conjunction has very often less than 10 conjuncts, `X` and `Y` are simple linear inequalities. These problems are easy to solve so I reckon my performance issue has more to do with scaffolding code.

My question is, how to reduce the cost of each call to this `unsat` function?

Comment: Creating the solver once and using push/pop on the empty state seems to increase the performance a tad. But not enough for my application.